# Get the value that has been selected in the selectOneMenu ListBox

Tags: java, jsf, listbox, selectonemenu

This is how my JSF looks like.

```
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{HotelDataForm.listHotel}">
           <f:selectItems value="#{HotelDataForm.listHotel}" var="user" itemValue="#{user[1]}" itemLabel="#{user[1]}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I need to get the value selected in my ListBox to my Java code, so i could write a business logic using it. So how do i get the value selected in the ListBox to my java code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{HotelDataForm.selectedHotel}">
```

The value-attribute of selectOneMenu is the setter that is invoked with the value of the selected item as a parameter. So in your bean, the method setSelectedHotel() is called.
In your code, you set the value to the list of items.

Comment: so if i call the getSelectedHotel () method, i should get the selected value is it ?

Comment: Well, you don't have to call getSelectedHotel because the variable is defined in the bean, so it's enough to access the value directly, but yes.

Comment: In my code `listHotel` is a `List<String>`, So how do i know which element in the `listHotel` (List<String>) have i called ? Help

Comment: Does your code work? I mean, does it show a list of the hotels? You know which element was selected because your selectedHotel variable is filled with the value of the selected hotel, in your case, a String with the hotel's name.

Comment: Yes it works it displays the names of all the hotels. I don't have a variable called `value="#{HotelDataForm.selectedHotel}">` in my code. its `value="#{HotelDataForm.listHotel}"` and its a `List<String>`.

Comment: Yes, I added it, because you need a variable to hold the selected value. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough about that in my answer.